# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: r.writeFileSync is not a function in jspdf.js

Tags: typescript, jspdf, polyfills, webpack-5, writefile

I'm currently trying to add export to PDF functionality to my React application using jsPdf. My application uses Webpack5, which I know has removed a number of polyfills that existed in Webpack4. I originally encountered a buffer is not defined error when trying to save the PDF, which I resolved by adding the buffer polyfill. However, since then I am receiving a new error when trying to save the PDF:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: r.writeFileSync is not a function
    at I.v.save (jspdf.js:13845:1)
```

Has anyone seen this error before and been able to resolve? I think it may be that I need to polyfill more node modules, but cannot identify which one will resolve this.

I have tried installing a number of packages such as:
"process": "^0.11.10"
"write-to-file-webpack": "^1.0.6" (which I believe now is only for Webpack4)
"stream-browserify": "^3.0.0"
Updating webpack.config.js file:

```
fallback: {
            stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
            buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
            process: require.resolve('process/browser'),

        },
```

```
plugins: [
            process: "process/browser",
            Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    ],
```

Also tried adding the following to fallback from reading issues others have experienced with Webpack5:
"fs": false,
"tls": false,
"net": false,
"path": false,
"zlib": false,
"http": false,
"https": false,
"stream": false,
"crypto": false,

I am still unable to identify what will resolve the r.writeFileSync is not a function.
Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you resolved this problem ?